# Synchronizing my project with GitHub

Tags: eclipse, github-api

I am working on a project X and the project X core source code is from GitHub. I want to:

1. Add my own classes to it.
2. Whenever they have fixes I want to be able to pull it to my project.
3. Lets say at the end of the day I want to commit my changes & the
   pull for fixes to my repository on GitHub (Most important thing).

What I did is (I have Github account and have repository ready):

1. I have GitHb application installed and all repositories inside
   "**GetHub**" folder.
2. I open Eclipse and I import the project X source code using Git and
   store the files inside **GetHub** folder.
3. I added my classes through eclipse then I want to commit them
4. The application detect that I have some changes to commit. The
   problem is the application detect that the project exist on Github
   and whenever I want to commit the changes to my repository that I
   created it tries to access the original repository for the project X
   and commit the changes there.

Is there away to have my project sync with the original code + add my own code + commit it to my repository?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Typically with git/Github, you commit to your own local git repository, then push it to Github.  I am not sure how your Eclipse setup is, but they way I would typically do it is:

-create project directories and pull from git using the command line

-import the project into Eclipse

-after you have saved your files, do

```
git add file1, file2, etc
git commit -m "whatever your message is"
git push
```

After you enter your username and password, git will push the files to Github and you should be able to go to your repository on Github and see your update immediately.

There are plenty of books and tutorials out there that should help you with learning git commands and managing git/Github repositories.